# Angularjs Function in Controller scope

Tags: function, angularjs, controller, scope

I have a strange thing:

my controller works, but getHash service is called on loading, instead on calling `saveit()` function on index html:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$http','getHash', function ($scope,$http, getHash) {

    $scope.keys = getHash.get(function(keys) {
        $scope.key = keys.key;
    });

    $scope.saveit = function () {

        $scope.formData = {
            'key' : $scope.key
        };

        console.log ($scope.formData);
        //Do Something with formData
   }   
}
```

This Example is not working, the `$scope.key` is empty, but the `getHash` Service is called as it should.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$http','getHash', function ($scope,$http, getHash) {

    $scope.saveit = function () {

        $scope.keys = getHash.get(function(keys) {
            $scope.key = keys.key;
        });

        $scope.formData = {
            'key' : $scope.key
        };

        console.log ($scope.formData);
        //Do Something with formData
   }   
}
```

Has anyone an explanation for this behavior? how can i get `$scope` in the function `saveit`?
or save variables to `$scope` inside `saveit`?

Thanks, Patrick

Comment: In the first case `$scope.keys` executes on load because it's calling what looks like a service. And since it's never called from within `saveit()` it obviously doesn't get called when you execute `saveit()`.

In the second case `$scope.keys` is run, but due to it's asynchronous nature the program continues onto `$scope.formData` and doesn't wait for `getHash.get(function(keys)` to finish executing.

The following might work better for you:
`$scope.keys = getHash.get(function(keys) { $scope.key = keys.key;  $scope.formData = { 'key' : $scope.key }; });`

Also a plunker would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got the async thing! I had to put in the rest of the code into the callback function of getHash, it's working now!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)